# cocos2d landscape game present portrait viewcontroller

Tags: ios, view, controller, cocos2d-iphone

my game uses cocos2d landscape mode. when I need to present view controllers, they are also in landscape mode, for example, game center and store view controller.

Store view controller works for ios6 and before (looks a bit weird since the content is still in portrait mode), but it crashes on ios7. game center still works fine.

Note that both store view controller and game center view controller still work perfectly for portrait mode on ios7.

So is it possible to set the store view controller to be portrait only? (while game center view controller still in landscape)

I use this code to present the store view controller:

```
if ([SKStoreProductViewController class] != nil) {
    //create store view controller
    SKStoreProductViewController *productController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    productController.delegate = (id<SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate>)self;
    //load product details
    NSDictionary *productParameters = @{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier:url};
    [productController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (!result) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


    [[(AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] navController] presentViewController:productController animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@?mt=8", url];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

}
```

the url above is an app id string

EDIT:

I tried

```
productController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```

but still it's still in landscape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass SKStoreProductViewController making it supporting only portait orientations like

```
@implementation PortaitStoreProductViewController

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}
```

and then use it like

```
SKStoreProductViewController *productController = [[PortaitStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
```